# How to solve undefine index?

Tags: php

How  to solve undefined index although i have started session in the top of the header file it shows undefined index?

> **The following error was shown:-**
>   Notice: Undefined index: signed_in in C:\xampp\htdocs\web_forum\header.php on line 26

line 26

```
if($_SESSION['signed_in'])
```

### header.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="description" content="A short description."/>
    <meta name="keywords" content="put, keywords, here"/>
    <title>Webinar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Webinar</h1>

        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="menu">
                <a class="item" href="index.php">Home</a> -
                <a class="item" href="create_topic.php">Create a topic</a> -
                <a class="item" href="create_cat.php">Create a category</a>



                <div id="userbar">
                <?php
        if($_SESSION['signed_in'])
        {
            echo 'Hello <b>' . htmlentities($_SESSION['user_name']) . '</b>. Not you? <a class="item" href="signout.php">Sign out</a>';
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<a class="item" href="signin.php">Sign in</a> or <a class="item" href="signup.php">create an account</a>';
        }
        ?>
                            </div>

                </div>
                <div id="content">
```

---

### footer.php

```
</div><!--content-->

        </div><!--wrapper-->

        <div id="footer">Created for webinar by Swastik Shrestha.</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how do you check if variable is set?

Comment: You never set `$_SESSION['signed_in']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `isset()` method like this:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['signed_in'])) { ... }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This question has already be answered many times.